# Is there an implicit in this call to flatMap?

Tags: scala, flatmap

In this code :

```
import java.io.File
def recursiveListFiles(f: File): Array[File] = {
  val these = f.listFiles
  these ++ these.filter(_.isDirectory).flatMap(recursiveListFiles)
}
```

taken from : [How do I list all files in a subdirectory in scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2637643/how-do-i-list-all-files-in-a-subdirectory-in-scala)

Why does `flatMap(recursiveListFiles)` compile ? as `recursiveListFiles` accepts a `File` parameter ? Is file parameter implicitly passed to `recursiveListFiles` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sort of. `flatMap` quite explicitly passes an argument to its own argument. This is the nature of a higher-order function -- you basically give it a callback, it calls the callback, and then it does something with the result. The only implicit thing happening is conversion of a method to a function type.

Any method can be converted to an equivalent function type. So `def recursiveListFiles(f: File): Array[File]` is equivalent to `File => Array[File]`, which is great, because on an `Array[File]`, you have `flatMap[B](f: File => Array[B]): Array[B]`, and your method's function type fits perfectly: the type parameter `B` is chosen to be `File`.

As mentioned in another answer, you could explicitly create that function by doing:

`these.filter(_.isDirectory).flatMap(file => recursiveListFiles(file))` or
`these.filter(_.isDirectory).flatMap(recursiveListFiles(_))` or
`these.filter(_.isDirectory).flatMap(recursiveListFiles _)`

In more complex circumstances, you might need to work with one of those more verbose options, but in your case, no need to bother.

Answer (score 1):

No because the expanded `flatMap` looks like:

```
flatMap(file => recursiveListFiles(file))
```

So each `file` in `these` is getting mapped to an `Array[File]`, which gets flattened in `flatMap`. No implicit magic here (in the way that you're asking).

Comment: Actually, there is; `Array[File]` is converted to a `WrappedArray[File]` by an implicit, since obviously Java arrays don't inherit from `GenTraversableOnce`.

Comment: But not in the way the OP is asking.

Comment: Yes, just a clarification in case someone misunderstands.

Comment: Technically, there's also the implicit `CanBuildFrom`

Answer (score 0):

[`flatMap`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.List@flatMap[B](f:A=%3Escala.collection.GenTraversableOnce[B]):List[B]) takes a function `f: (A) ⇒ GenTraversableOnce[B]` to return `List[B]`.

In your case, it is taking `recursiveListFiles` which is a `File ⇒ Array[File]` to therefore return a `List[File]`. This resulting `List[File]` is then concatenated to `these`.