# Reading multiple csv files at different folder depths

Tags: scala, csv, apache-spark, dataframe, wildcard

I want to recursively read all csv files in a given folder into a Spark SQL `DataFrame` using a single path, if possible.

My folder structure looks something like this and I want to include all of the files with one path:

1. `resources/first.csv`
2. `resources/subfolder/second.csv`
3. `resources/subfolder/third.csv`

This is my code:

```
def read: DataFrame =
      sparkSession
        .read
        .option("header", "true")
        .option("inferSchema", "true")
        .option("charset", "UTF-8")
        .csv(path)
```

Setting `path` to `.../resource/*/*.csv` omits 1. while `.../resource/*.csv` omits 2. and 3.

I know `csv()` also takes multiple strings as path arguments, but want to avoid that, if possible.

**note:** I know my question is similar to [How to import multiple csv files in a single load?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37639956/how-to-import-multiple-csv-files-in-a-single-load), except that I want to include files of *all contained folders*, independent of their location within the main folder.

Comment: does a recursive file search solve your problem? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2637643/how-do-i-list-all-files-in-a-subdirectory-in-scala

Comment: Technically yes, but as I said, I wanted to avoid having to pass multiple arguments to `csv()`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If there are only csv files and only one level of subfolder in your `resources` directory then you can use `resources/**`.

**EDIT**

Else you can use Hadoop `FileSystem` class to recursively list every csv files in your `resources` directory and then pass the list to `.csv()`

```
    val fs = FileSystem.get(new Configuration())
    val files = fs.listFiles(new Path("resources/", true))
    val filePaths = new ListBuffer[String]
    while (files.hasNext()) {
        val file = files.next()
        filePaths += file.getPath.toString
    }

    val df: DataFrame = spark
        .read
        .options(...)
        .csv(filePaths: _*)
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. Yes, there are only csv files. Unfortunately `resources/**` doesn't do the trick: it only retrieves files in `resources/`, but omits files in `resources/subfolder`

Comment: I just realized that I'd temporarily messed up my testing scenario - you were right of course, `/**` _does_ work after all. Sorry for the confusion. :)

Comment: I had some ambiguity on where the Path was. I didn't know if it was in the default scala, hadoop, java.io, or the java.nio package. All were in the Hadoop package, including Path.
You can import them with `import org.apache.hadoop.fs.{FileSystem, Path}` and the Configuration with `import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration`.

Comment: I tried using this in the AWS glue job, it didn't work any suggestions?

Answer (score 7):

You could use `RecursiveFileLookup` in spark3 now.

```scala
val recursiveLoadedDF = spark.read
  .option("recursiveFileLookup", "true")
  .csv("resources/")
```

for more reference: [recursive-file-lookup](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-generic-options.html#recursive-file-lookup)

Comment: I tried using this in the aws glue job, but it didn't work. Any suggestions? Thanks