# File wildcard use *

Tags: java, scala

I am trying to read a file which has name: *K2ssal.timestamp*.
I want to handle the time stamp part of the file name as wildcard.
How can I achieve this ?
tried * after file name but not working.

```
var getK2SSal: Iterator[String] = Source.fromFile("C://Users/nrakhad/Desktop/Work/Data stage migration/Input files/K2Ssal.*").getLines()
```

Comment: hi and welcome: please read here -> https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , then edit your question

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2637643/how-do-i-list-all-files-in-a-subdirectory-in-scala ?

Comment: perhaps search for files in that directory with such names then open whatever files match

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Files.newDirectoryStream` with directory + glob:

```
import java.nio.file.{Paths, Files}

val yourFile = Files.newDirectoryStream(
  Paths.get("/path/to/the/directory"),       // where is the file?
  "K2Ssal.*"                                 // glob of the file name
).iterator.next                              // get first match
```

Answer (score 1):

Misconception on your end: *unless* the library call is specifically implemented to do so, using a wildcard simply doesn't work like you expect it to.

Meaning: a *file system* doesn't know about wildcards. It only knows about existing files and folders. The fact that you can put `*` on certain commands, and that the wildcard is replaced with file names is a *property* of the tool(s) you are using. And most often, programming APIs that allow you to query the file system do **not** include that special wild card handling.

In other words: there is no sense in adding that asterisk like that.

You have to step back and write code that actively *searches* for files itself. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2637643/how-do-i-list-all-files-in-a-subdirectory-in-scala) are some examples for scala.

Answer (score 0):

You can read the directory and filter on files based upon the string.

```
val l = new File("""C://Users/nrakhad/Desktop/Work/Data stage migration/Input files/""").listFiles
val s = l.filter(_.toString.contains("K2Ssal."))
```