# Read files recursively in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to read a set of XML files nested in many folders into sequence files in spark. I can read the file names using function recursiveListFiles from [How do I list all files in a subdirectory in scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2637643/how-do-i-list-all-files-in-a-subdirectory-in-scala).

```
import java.io.File
def recursiveListFiles(f: File): Array[File] = {
 val these = f.listFiles
 these ++ these.filter(_.isDirectory).flatMap(recursiveListFiles)
}
```

But how to read the file content as separate column here?

Answer (score 0):

What about using sparks wholeTextFiles method? And parsing the XML yourself afterwards?

Comment: I tried the wholeTextFiles method but I cant use .xml that is only to select the xml files in the folders. something like `sc.wholeTextFiles("mainpath/*.xml")`