# Get all the files of a specific folder inside a parent folder using scala

Tags: scala

I have a requirement to get all files inside a specific folder under one parent folder. Here is an example of that. My requirement is to get all the files of 15M folder which reside in multiple folders under one parent folder.

Parent/Sub-Folder/15M/folder1/Abc.txt,Parent/Folder12/folder23/15M/Folder1/CDE.txt

Can somebody please provide some suggestion on this using Scala?

Thanks

Comment: this post can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2637643/how-do-i-list-all-files-in-a-subdirectory-in-scala

Comment: Hi Tim, My question is about finding a particular folder name inside multiple parent folders not the files, the post you redirected says about fetching all the files of specific format. As I mentioned in the above example I want to get 15M folder in all parent folders and then retrieve its contents.

Comment: I apologize. The intention was to share with you that with scala you can use  java apis to obtain your goals. In that post of the above comment a user talk about it.  If you decide to use java api this other link can be more helpful: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/find.html.